# Merge CocoaPods branch into a Carthage one - how?

Tags: git, merge, cocoapods, branch, carthage

I have one project, where the develop branch was using CocoaPods, but one of the developers decided to remove it and use Carthage instead. The feature branch is using CocoaPods, because it was created one month before the transition in the develop branch. Now I have develop (Carthage) and feature (CocoaPods) and I want to have the changes from the feature implemented into the develop, but without the Pods.

Is it possible and if yes - how, to merge the CocoaPods branch into the Carthage one and leave the CocoaPods behind? I want to have my changes from the feature (CocoaPods) to be implemented into the develop (Carthage), but without the Pods.

I have never tried this and I will be very happy if you share some tutorial or something like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two different projects in one repo?

Comment: No, I have one project, where the develop branch was using CocoaPods, but one of the developers decided to remove it and use Carthage instead. The feature branch is using CocoaPods, because it was created one month before the transition in the develop branch. Now I have develop (Carthage) and feature (CocoaPods) and I want to have the changes from the feature implemented into the develop, but without the Pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a branch using Carthage, I will assume your dependencies support frameworks, enabling Carthage, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814370/6309).

I would then go the the CocoaPods branch, and make a new commit to that branch where you would have:

- removed/cleaned Cocoapods from the working tree (see "[How to Remove CocoaPods](https://medium.com/xcblog/carthage-or-cocoapods-that-is-the-question-1074edaafbcb#100c)"),
- referenced your dependencies with Carthage

Then try and merge that branch to pick up the file differences you want.